Use an existing Windows DLL as a part of React Native Windows application
I am currently working on a project to create a GUI for PICT. I am having trouble figuring out how to design the project at a high level. For context, this is my first time developing a Windows application.
My current design is to use React Native for Windows for the GUI as that is the tech I am most familiar with. However, the challenge comes from trying to integrate PICT into my project. React Native for Windows projects result in UWP applications, and from the documentation I read there seems to be a lot of difficulty porting existing C++ code so that it can be used in a UWP application. I am assuming I could do this through PICT's DLL, which exposes functionality that I could hopefully call from the JavaScript code. I am currently anticipating writing a custom native C++ module to do this, but honestly could be way off. What is the best/easiest way to go about integrating this DLL into my project? Is it even feasible or should I consider a different GUI framework?
I have tried reading through the following Windows documentation: How to Use Existing C++ Code in a UWP app and Alternatives to Windows APIs in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps.
